# py2app with anaconda Python 3 "missing constraints" error

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, anaconda

I am trying to compile a bare-bones wxPython project in Python 3 using py2app.

```
py2app                    0.13                      <pip>
wxPython                  4.0.0a3.dev3059+4a5c5d9   <pip>
Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
OS X 10.12.4
```

Here is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000) # need this to prevent max recursion depth reached                                                                      

APP = ['wx_py2app.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'plist': {'PyRuntimeLocations':
                     ['/Users/***/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5m.dylib',
                      '/Users/***/Python/simple_examples/dist/wx_py2app.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpython3.5m.dylib']}
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Here is my wxPython code:

```
import wx

class simpleapp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, wx_id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx_id, title, size=(100, 100))
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = simpleapp_wx(None, -1, 'my application')
    app.MainLoop()
```

I had to make a few patches.  First, I had to hard code /Users/***/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5m.dylib into py2app/build_app.py, or else it would look for libpython3.5.dylib instead and crash here:

```
ValueError: '/Users/***/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5.dylib'
```

Second, I patched PyQt5/uic/port_v2/load_plugin.py to avoid a syntax error, and PyQt5/uic/port_v2/ascii_upper.py which was using deprecated string.maketrans.

My bare-bones project works fine in alias mode, but in non-alias mode the project compiles, but then when I open it it immediately terminates:

```
Detected missing constraints for <private>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.
```

As a side note, my project does work without this problem when I compile it in alias mode.  Otherwise, I haven't been able to figure out anything about this error.  How can I debug or fix this?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem.

Could you specify what you mean by "compile in alias mode?"

I just need a demo to work as a proof of concept, and I keep getting this same crash with this same error.

Comment: See explanation here:  https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/.  Uses this syntax: python setup.py py2app -A